# Group by float values by range

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a data frame that looks like that:

```
Result
0.001
0.000
-0.001
0.005
0.002
0.003
0.004
0.001
3.400
3.401
3.405
3.402
0.003
0.004
0.001
4.670
-0.001
4.675
4.672
0.003
3.404
```

I would like to group values by some interval (let's say ±0.005 from first 'not already existing' value),
so here I would have it grouped as:

```
Result GROUP_AVG
0.001  0.003
0.000  0.003
-0.001  0.003
0.005  0.003
0.002  0.003
0.003  0.003
0.004  0.003
0.001  0.003
3.400  3.403
3.401  3.403
3.405  3.403
3.402  3.403
0.003  0.003
0.004  0.003
0.001  0.003
4.670  4.673
-0.001  0.003
4.675  4.673
4.672  4.673
0.003  0.003
3.404  3.403
```

Now, I am doing it inefficient way:

1. Check if `row_value` is in ±0.005 from any item from `averages_set["value"]`
2. If no, create new entity in `averages_set` with `"value": row_value, "average": row_value, count: 1`
3. If yes, update `averages_set[i]["average"]=(average * count + row_value)/(count+1)`, and also `count=count+1`
4. After all the rows are iterated, add column to basic dataset and change it for each row based on its distance to `averages_set[i]["value"]`, change the new column value for row with `averages_set[i]["average"]` as I need to have average anyway for further operations. And the average can be actually treated as discrete value without bigger problems for further operations.

I have used `pandas.groupby` before, and it works great for discrete values. Is there a way to, for example, group by based on float value, taking into account e.g. ±0.5 from the first new value that occurred? It was much more efficient than my algorithm, and I could easily calculate average(and not only) for each group.

Comment: how did the "-3.401" in the first df became"3.401" without the minus sign in the second one?

Comment: Sorry it's my bad, fixing it right now :)

Comment: Note that, if I read your definition correctly, the result is order dependent: `[0, 0.006, 0.004]` would yield two groups (`[0, 0.005]`) whereas `[0, 0.004, 0.006]` would yield a single one (`[0.0033..]`). Aside from that, one thing that comes to mind is vector quantization (in 1 dimension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is difficult to solve optimally (i.e., find the minimum number of groups). As noted in the comments, your approach is order-dependent: `[0, 0.006, 0.004]` would yield two groups (`[0, 0.005]`) whereas `[0, 0.004, 0.006]` would yield a single one (`[0.0033..]`). Furthermore, it is a greedy agglomerative grouping, which cuts many of the possible groups, often including the optimal one.

Here is one approach using agglomerative clustering. It is between `O(n log n)` and `O(n^2)` for `n` points: roughly 61ms for 1K points, but 3.2s for 5K points on my machine. It also requires a slight change of definition: we represent groups by a "center" (the center of the bounding box) rather than an average centroid.

We use the `linkage='complete'` linkage type (so the overall diameter of the cluster is the determining metric) and set the maximum distance (that diameter) to be twice your "tolerance".

**Example**

```py
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

def quantize(df, tolerance=0.005):
    # df: DataFrame with only the column(s) to quantize
    model = AgglomerativeClustering(distance_threshold=2 * tolerance, linkage='complete',
                                    n_clusters=None).fit(df)
    df = df.assign(
        group=model.labels_,
        center=df.groupby(model.labels_).transform(lambda v: (v.max() + v.min()) / 2),
    )
    return df
```

On your data, it takes 4.4ms and results in the following `df`:

```py
>>> quantize(df[['Result']], tolerance=0.005)
    Result  group  center
0    0.001      0  0.0020
1    0.000      0  0.0020
2   -0.001      0  0.0020
3    0.005      0  0.0020
4    0.002      0  0.0020
5    0.003      0  0.0020
6    0.004      0  0.0020
7    0.001      0  0.0020
8    3.400      2  3.4025
9    3.401      2  3.4025
10   3.405      2  3.4025
11   3.402      2  3.4025
12   0.003      0  0.0020
13   0.004      0  0.0020
14   0.001      0  0.0020
15   4.670      1  4.6725
16  -0.001      0  0.0020
17   4.675      1  4.6725
18   4.672      1  4.6725
19   0.003      0  0.0020
20   3.404      2  3.4025
```

**Visualization**

You can visualize the corresponding dendrogram with [`scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html):

```py
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

Z = linkage(pdist(df[['Result']]), 'complete')
dn = dendrogram(Z)
plt.axhline(2 * tolerance, c='k')
plt.ylim(0, 2.1 * tolerance)
```

[image]

There are three clusters below the threshold indicated by `2 * tolerance`.

**Speed**

The hierarchical clustering with `linkage='complete'` is generally `O(n^2)`. In some cases though, there might be a bit of saving because of the `distance_threshold`. To see the effect of this, we use [`perfplot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) and explore performance v. size of `df`:

```py
import perfplot

tolerance = 0.005
base2_max = int(np.round(np.log2(20_000)))
o = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, tolerance * n, size=n), columns=['Result']),
    kernels=[quantize],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(8, base2_max + 1)],
)
```

The time is above `n log(n)`, but clearly not quite `n^2`:

```py
k_ = o.n_range
t_ = o.timings_s[0]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(10, 3), tight_layout=True)
axes = iter(axes)
ax = next(axes)
ax.loglog(k_, t_)
ax.set_title('time')
ax.set_xlabel('n')

ax = next(axes)
ax.semilogx(k_, t_ / (np.log(k_) * k_))
ax.set_title('relative to $\mathcal{O}(n\log{}n)$')
ax.set_xlabel('n')
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

ax = next(axes)
ax.semilogx(k_, t_ / k_ ** 2)
ax.set_title('relative to $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$')
ax.set_xlabel('n')
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

[image]